# add google markers in javascript object

Tags: jquery, html, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have google map, along with markers,each marker represent individual establishment. I want to store maker in object rather than array so I can add additional information along with each marker on specific index.

I tried like this but its not working for reason,

```
//initialize global var..
var myMarkers = {
    markers : ""
};
var counter =0;

function createMarker(place) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: placeLoc,
        icon: IconType[place.types[0]]
    });

    myMarkers[counter] = {
        markers: marker
    };

    counter++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i have found another solution to this problem.... say example i want to store each marker types or establishment, rather then storing in another JavaScript object, use existing marker object and add details in it.

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: placeLoc,
    icon: IconType[place.types[0]],
    category: place.types               //additional detail
});

     markers.push(marker);

alert(markers[0].category);
```